# Button on ListAdapter

Tags: android

I have button on items in my list adapter. The problem occurs when I click the button. The action is performed on the right item, but it disables wrong button. 
My code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_friend, parent, false);

        user = userList.get(position);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.user_image);

Picasso.with(JSONUserAdapter.this.getContext()).load("https://s3.amazonaws.com/profiles-pictures/"+ user.getPath()).into(imageView);


        sendRequest = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.sendRequest);


        sendRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sendFriendRequest();
                disabledAdd();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: user = userList.get(position); Make this valable local final.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to catch click events for the buttons inside the rows of `ListView`. Each row of `ListView` is already clickable. Set the `onItemClickListener` for the `ListView`:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long l) {
           //DO SOMETHING HERE
           //Use "position" to get the index of item clicked
     }
});
```

Comment: Unless you want separate functionality available on list item click.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see that we had defined the "User" object as a globel variable and it will store the last postions item data.

So when you will click on any button the last items data will be reflected.

```
 {UserType}Object user = userList.get(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Tag on `View`

Use like this:

```
sendRequest.setTag(user);
```

And When user clicks item let's get data from tag like this

```
sendRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Here you have user that was clicked. 
                User user = v.getTag();
                sendFriendRequest();
                disabledAdd();

            }
});
```